# Port forwarding based on hostname

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I have a couple of web based services running on my home computer using different ports. I also have several A:s directed to my home server for these named services i:e service_name.server.com (server.com is however not directed towards my home server).

All incoming connections will be made from a web browser. Is there any way I can direct users connecting to service.server.com silently to a specific port? For example, I type `rutorrent.server.com` and automatically load `rutorrent.server.com:[rutorrentport]`

Answer (score 0):

Lets say for example your torrent service runs on port 5555, set the port forward on your router as a custom forward, then just attach the port number to the end of the URL like so - rutorrent.server.com:5555.

You could hide the port number in a link so all the users will see is the URL or whatever you specify.

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Adding the port number to the URL is **NOT** what I wanted to do. What I'm trying to do is to have access to e.g. `torrent.server.com` and `media.server.com` automatically forward to different ports. The clients would send their requests on port `80` since all they do is type what they want to access in their browser.